# Quartz.net: FireAtTime doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am trying to implement Quartz.net in one of my projects.
I am using `NthIncludedDayTrigger` cause I want my trigger to fire every 5 months at a certain time. Here is the code:

```
NthIncludedDayTrigger trigger = new NthIncludedDayTrigger(triggerName, groupName);
trigger.Description = "My trigger";
trigger.StartTimeUtc = startDate;
trigger.EndTimeUtc = endDate;
trigger.IntervalType = NthIncludedDayTrigger.IntervalTypeMonthly;
trigger.N = 5;
trigger.FireAtTime = "09:00";

DateTime? Check = DateTime.Now;
DateTime? When = trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(Check.Value);
```

As you can see I want my trigger to run at 9AM (my timezone is GMT => Greenwich).
When I check (`GetFireTimeAfter`) the next fire time I can see it is at 8AM. 
I've checked the timezone `trigger.TimeZone` and it is absolutely fine.
Is anyone here who can try to help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be sure, you should use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now` to get a `DateTime` that has its `Kind` set to `UTC`.